# Is it possible to rename properties in a custom control that were inherited from another control?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I want to create a custom control which extends `Image` and has a `Source` property that acts completely normal, but I want to label it something other than `Source`. Is that possible?

The reason is because my custom control is a `ColorableImage`, and I want both the `OriginalSource` and `ColoredSource` to be retrievable. I can make the control's `Source` merely pull from `ColoredSource`, since that is what is being displayed, but then I have two properties doing the same thing. I could also merely keep the name as `Source`, but I think that name is slightly confusing given the situation.

I also thought that maybe I could override the `Source` property and just hide it by making it unable to be set, but it appears that isn't possible.

Comment: Why do you need an explicit ColoredSource property?  I disagree that leaving it as Source is confusing.  To answer your question I believe the answer is no, without doing something "hackish" specific to C#.  You can change most everything about a property with [OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.overridemetadata(v=vs.110).aspx), but the name is not one of them.

Comment: Just for that reason, pretty much... Perhaps I will just use the Source property, if the answer turns out to be too complex for the task

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new class that does not descend from `Image` but from `Image's` base class, and use an `Image` instance internally.  Then you can add your own `ColoredSource` and an `OriginalSource` propties that then affect the internal `Image` instance's `Source` property.  That is, something like this:

```
public class ColoredImage : FrameworkElement {

    private Image Image { get; set; }

    public static readonly ColoredSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "ColoredSource", typeof( ImageSource ), typeof( ColoredImage ), new PropertyMetaData( null, new PropertyChangedCallback( OnColoredSourceChanged ) ) );

    public ColoredSource {
        get { return (ImageSource) GetValue( ColoredImageProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ColoredImageProperty, value ); }
    }

    public ImageSource Originalsource {
        get { return Image.Source; }
        set { Image.Source = value; }
    }

    private static void OnColoredSourceChanged( DependencyObject d,
DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e ) {
        ColoredImage instance = d as ColoredImage;
        instance.Image.Source = e.NewValue as ImageSource;
    }

    // The rest of your logic here

}
```

Comment: I considered this, but I am too afraid that I will not get all of the functionality of an Image (such as resizing differently), and even worse, I might not realize that my control is acting differently than an image normally would.

Comment: What I didn't say or show was that you would also have to add one event, property & method for each member is implemented in `Image`, calling the same property or method of the internal `Image` object.  The MSDN documentation will tell you which members are inherited from the base class & which are implemented by `Image`.  The docs will help you get everything that's exposed.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a class such as 'Base' and set a public or protected property.

```
public string MyMessage { get; set; }
```

Instantiate it or not in a constructor in the base class.

Then create another class that INHERITS this class.  Like 'Dervied' class and make it inherit at the top.

```
public class Derived : Base
```

You now can get all the members of the base class provided they are public/protected.  You can  form them in the base and then just get them set always.  Else you can form them in the derived class.